# Comparing 3 columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to compare 3 columns in PySpark (percentages summing to 100%) to create a new one which would contain the column name of the max of the 3 columns or, in case the max is not unique, contains the name of the columns that have the same value. I have seen some similar examples here but they don't handle the case when the max is not unique. Below is my brute-force solution, but it takes so much time to run to become useless:

```
df\
  .withColumn("MaxName", 
      F.when( (col(A)>col(B)) & (col(A)>col(C)), "A")\
      .when( (col(B)>col(A)) & (col(B)>col(C)), "B")\
      .when( (col(C)>col(A)) & (col(C)>col(B)), "C")\
      .when( (col(A)==col(B)) &\
            (col(A)>col(C)) | (col(B)>col(C)), "AB")\
      .when( (col(C)==col(B)) | (col(C)==col(A)) &\
            (col(C)>col(B)) | (col(C)>col(A)), "CAB")\
      .otherwise("ABC")
```

Any insights to build a more efficient solution?

Comment: what's your spark version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you can compare with `greatest` and return the column names , then concat:
Example:

Input:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)),
                                        columns=list('ABCDE')))
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 84| 84| 84| 86| 19|
| 41| 66| 82| 40| 71|
| 57|  7| 12| 10| 65|
| 88| 28| 14| 34| 21|
| 54| 72| 37| 76| 58|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Proposed solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols = ['A','B','C']
df.withColumn("max_of_ABC",F.concat_ws("",
             *[F.when(F.col(i) == F.greatest(*cols),i) for i in cols])).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|max_of_ABC|
+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
| 84| 84| 84| 86| 19|       ABC|
| 41| 66| 82| 40| 71|         C|
| 57|  7| 12| 10| 65|         A|
| 88| 28| 14| 34| 21|         A|
| 54| 72| 37| 76| 58|         B|
+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: Awesome solution.